# How to write code that if something happens nothing else happens afterward?

Tags: java

Lets say if the last level of a game is beaten then you dont show a dialog box asking if the player wants to go on to the next level, but rather to the mainmenu. SO basically if something happens the things that are supposed to happen afterward dont.

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    final ImageIcon pokeballIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bacojul15\\Pictures\\pokeball5.gif");
    final ImageIcon pokemoneggIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bacojul15\\Pictures\\nidoking.gif");
    final ImageIcon pokemonredIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bacojul15\\Pictures\\red.gif");

    String userAnswer = answertextArea.getText().trim();

        if (userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers.get(questionNumber))) {

            answerLabel.setText("Correct");
            levelScore ++;
            triviagui.totalScore ++;


        } else {
            answerLabel.setText("Incorrect");
        }
        answertextArea.setText("");
        questionNumber++;
        if(questionNumber == questions.size()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score for this level was : " + levelScore + " out of 10. \n Your total score is " + triviagui.totalScore, "Scores",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, pokeballIcon );
                if(difficulty == 3){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good job you beat the game! \n Your total score was " + triviagui.totalScore + " out of 30.", "Thanks for playing!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, pokemonredIcon);
                        triviagui.questionFrame.setVisible(false);
                        triviagui.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                int leveloptionPane = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to go on to the next level?" , "Next Level?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, levelScore, pokemoneggIcon);
            if(leveloptionPane == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    difficulty++;
                    triviagui.questionFrame.setVisible(false);
                    triviagui.questionFrame=new QuestionFrame(difficulty);
                    triviagui.questionFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
            if(leveloptionPane == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                triviagui.questionFrame.setVisible(false);
                triviagui.mainFrame.setVisible(true);                    
        }
            return;
        }
        updateQuestionScore();

}
```

Comment: As an aside, you'll probably be re-using those icons throughout the program, so why re-read them every time needed? Consider reading them once on program start-up and storing them in variables that can be used and re-used. As another aside, I'd try to refactor that code so that the logic portion, is not inside of the GUI. If your code is shortened by calling methods, it will be easier to debug, easier to enhance (such as your current desire to enhance or correct program flow based on state).

Answer (score 4):

You simply want to do:

```
if(something happens) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to jump out from method use

> return;

example of something like that:

```
    public void myMethod(){
    if(mynumber==5){
       doThis();
        }else{
        return;
        }
      /*
       *do something else  <- this wont be executed if number doesnt equal 5 
       *cause we are already out of method.
       */
}
```

If you dont want to jump out from whole method bud only form part of it for instance loop.

```
break;
```

example of that:

```
  public void myMethod(String[] stringArr){
   for(String s:stringArr){
       if(s.equals("hello")){
            break; //get me out of this loop now !
       }else{
          s+="alriight";
            }
       }
      }
      doSomethingElse();//this will be executed even if you go thru break; you are still inside method dont forget.You are just out of loop

}
```

There are better uses for that maybe examples aint best bud you will understand how to use it form this:).

When you use break or return.In eclipse for instance you will be shown Where you actually exit. it will highlight "}"

Comment: thanks but java says "break outside switch or loop" ohh btw i am putting it at the end of the 2nd if statement.

Comment: I added some examples.Not sure about braces cause im putting them from my head (hopefully correctly)will try to fix if i notice bad ones.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

You can `return` from a method.

You can `break` to exit a loop or `continue` to start the next iteration of the loop.

You can use an 'else' to only execute other code if the first section did not execute.

You can set a boolean flag variable and then check for that elsewhere in your code.

Depending on what you are trying to do each of these is sometimes the best way, sometimes not the best way.